# Multiplying odd numbers in a string

Tags: python, function, multiplication

Implement a function called mult_odd_digits(n) which receives a positive integer n and returns the product of its digits that are odd.

• If there are no odd digits, return 1.

Examples:

```
>>> mult_odd_digits(5638) 
15
```

---

```
 def mult_odd_digits(n):
    for i in n:  # replace this with your implementation
       if i%2==0:
           mult=i*(i+1)
       else:
           print ('1')
   return mult
result=mult_odd_digits(5638)
print (result)
```

Comment: `int` values are not iterable; you can't iterate over the (decimal) digits like this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a homework question verbatim without effort to solve yourself

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: @ChrisCharles There's no restriction against homework.

Comment: Ok, I've retracted my close vote.

Comment: `reduce(operator.mul, [int(i) if int(i) % 2 else 1 for i in str(5638)])`

Answer (score -1):

Integers are not iterable. You can convert the number to a string, then convert each character to an integer.

You're also not multiplying the digits by each other. When you get an even digit, you multiply it by the next number -- why? And why are you printing `1` for every odd digit?

```
def mult_odd_digits(n):
    digits = map(int, str(n))
    product = 1
    for digit in digits:
        if digit % 2 == 1: # odd digit
            product *= digit
    return product
```

If you're not supposed to convert it to a string, you can use the modulus operator to get each digit.

```
def mult_odd_digits(n):
    product = 1
    while n != 0:
        digit = n % 10 # last digit of n
        if digit % 2 == 1:
            product *= digit
        n //= 10 # remove last digit
```